# json parsing and append result takes eternity

Tags: jquery, json

I have a file that I got online listing every cities in france (36k entries)

the file looks like this

> [
>   {"ville_code_postal":"01190","ville_nom_reel":"Ozan","ville_longitude_deg":"4.91667","ville_latitude_deg":"46.3833"}

Jquery

I perform a parsing and then I include the result in an `ul` block

```
let jsurl = '{/literal}{$urls.js_url}{literal}';

var ufcities;

$.getJSON(
        jsurl+'villes_france.json',
        function(ufd) {
            ufcities = ufd;
            $.each(ufcities,function(i,o) {
                $('.list').append("<li><strong>"+o.ville_nom_reel+"</strong><i>"+o.ville_code_postal+"</i></li>");
            });
        }
);
```

The `$.each()` method take over a minute to print the entire list in the `ul` block and the page freez during this long process

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to make it right?

Comment: Strongly suggest you NOT hit the DOM on every loop.  Post the relevant HTML so we can also help make this better hitting the DOM 36K times is a pretty large task.

Comment: 36K entries should be an immediate red flag.  I would highly advise changing the logic in favor of either a paging version of the results, or an auto suggest where the user can type part of what they want and the options are filtered down.  36K results does not make sense to display to a user all at once, and would be considered the classical UI/UX mistake of creating a Wall of Text

Comment: @Taplar my goal was to hide this list and when the user start to type in, I show him the li element that match his request. So you will go for a .filter method? Can you show me how?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you have the whole thing before your eyes, really :(

Comment: You wouldn't build the results on load.  You would store the results for later use.  Then as your user types into whatever inputs you have, you'd have `input` bindings on them that would then filter the results, and periodically rebuild the results on the page.

Comment: @Taplar Ok, but as soon as he will put a finger on his keyboard he will have the same parsing method as the $.each no? or are you talking about obj.filter() instead of each()?

Comment: Yes filter.  And it's not a parsing issue.  As Mark Schultheiss mentioned earlier, your provided logic was touching the DOM for every record, which is what slows down the display dramatically.  Your filter should reduce the number of elements you build down below some threshold, and even then, it should build all the html and then append them all to the DOM in one statement

Comment: @Taplar ok, I got it. I will search more further for a better way to do it. Thanks for advices